# Android BottomSheetBehavior get button always on screen and in botton

Tags: android

Hi I want to get a `Button` which is **always display** on a screen in bottom.

I have a `BottomSheetBehavior` in layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500sp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="85dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nsv"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10sp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_event_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_about_event_title"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_where"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_event_description"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I have a button on bottom when I scrollup view. 
When my application is created this view I do not have a button on a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to wrap your root layout in to `LinearLayout`, so in pseudocode:

```
-  LinearLayout                       <---  new wrapper for whole layout

        -  CoordinatorLayout          <---  wrapper for BottomSheet

                  - Main Content      <---  general screen content  (can be as "include")

                  - BottomSheet       <---  swipable from bottom  (can be as "include")

        -  LinearLayout               <---  wrapper for bottom buttons
```

So you can conert yout layout as here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <include layout="@layout/content" />

        <include layout="@layout/sheet_event" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="left button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="right button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And that should be the final effect:

[image]